# ActiveRecord::Relation issue checking for nil? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

On the following query I get objects as return value (and thus checking for no results using **.nil?** works just fine:

```
  store = Store.where(:some_id => myobj.some_id.to_i).first
  unless store.nil?
```

But on this next code I get return type of ActiveRecord::Relation and checking using **.nil?** fails!

```
existing_store = Store.where(:some_str => myobj.some_str).not_hidden().active()
if existing_store.nil?
```

**1. Why is that?**

**2. How can I check for no results in this case?**

**3. How could I check for no records return in general when using find() or where()**

Rails 3.1 has really made this confusing.

Comment: `not_hidden` and `active` are scopes I assume? And what does calling `#nil?` return exactly?

Comment: yes, those are scopes... and calling .nil? is always false because the return value is an empty array (and thus never nil)

Comment: As already suggested below, I'd use `#empty?` then.

Comment: For both cases or only when the return type is `ActiveRecord::Relation` ?

Comment: In my opinion, using `#where` only is for situations in which you want to find several records. If so, check with `#empty?`. If you want to find a single record, use `#first` and check with `nil?`.

Comment: So if I want to only get 1 record based on a text field, which function should I use to retreive?

Comment: One record based on a text field? Don't get that. You just want to retrieve a record from the db with one attribute?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4773/discussion-between-tbuehlmann-and-hopstream)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `blank?`, `nil?` is true, if it's really `nil` (single instance of `NilClass`), but your second example always will return an Array, maybe empty, if there are no results, but an Array nonetheless. `blank?` checks for empty arrays, empty strings, nil and false values.

If you have problems with `blank?` not behaving as expected you can check for `first.nil?`

Comment: After extensive testing, `blank?` and it's opposite `present?` turned out to be the best options for testing return values for active record.

Answer (score 3):

Because in first case you try to check an instance in the secound you got `Array` and an array isnt `nil`, its an `Array` even if its empty. You should use `empty?` to check this!

Comment: but I get an array even if I do .first() in the second query.

Comment: Really what is returned when you try `Store.where(:some_str => myobj.some_str).first.class`?

Comment: ActiveRecord::Relation -- I'm using rails 3.1